# Estou com problemas para persistir os dados no BD

Tags: java, jsp

Eu estou conectada com o banco postgreSQL, coloquei o driver postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar. Quando clico em cadastrar aparece essa janela não está listando nem persistindo. O problema é que não aparece mensagem de erro no console. Alguém já passou por isso para me ajudar?

[image: Estou utilizando só o method get para fazer requisições de formlário]

A página jsp está assim:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Cadastro do Aluno</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="alunoCONTROLLER" method="get" >
    <input type="hidden" name="operacao" value="inserir" >

    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"/><br/>

    <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
    <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone"/><br/>

    <label for="email" >Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br/>

    <label for="endereco">Endereço:</label>
    <input type="text" id="endereco" name="endereco"><br/>

    <label for="matricula">Matrícula:</label>
    <input type="text" id="matricula" name="matricula"><br/>

    <label for="idade">Idade:</label>
    <input type="text" id="idade" name="idade"><br/>

    <label for="ativo">Ativo:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo"><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Cadastre">
</form>
```

**O controller está assim:**

```
package CONTROLLER;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import DAO.AlunoDAO;
import MODEL.Aluno;

@WebServlet("/alunoCONTROLLER")
public class AlunoCONTROLLER extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public AlunoCONTROLLER() {
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    AlunoDAO dao = new AlunoDAO();
    Aluno aluno = new Aluno();

    String operacao = request.getParameter("operacao");

    switch(operacao){
    case "incluir":
        aluno.setNome(request.getParameter("nome"));
        aluno.setAtivo(Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("ativo")));
        aluno.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        aluno.setEndereco(request.getParameter("endereco"));
        aluno.setIdade(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idade")));
        aluno.setMatricula(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("matricula")));
        aluno.setTelefone(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("telefone")));
        dao.save(aluno);

        response.sendRedirect("listar.jsp");
        break;

    case "deleter":
        aluno.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
        dao.delete(aluno);
        response.sendRedirect("listar.jsp");

        break;

    case "atualizar":

        aluno.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
        aluno.setNome(request.getParameter("nome"));
        aluno.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        aluno.setEndereco(request.getParameter("endereco"));
        aluno.setIdade(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idade")));
        aluno.setMatricula(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("matricula")));
        aluno.setTelefone(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("telefone")));
        aluno.setAtivo(Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("ativo")));

        dao.update(aluno);
        response.sendRedirect("listar.jsp");
        break;  
    }
  }
}
```

**E o listar:**

```
<%@page import="MODEL.Aluno"%>
<%@page import="DAO.AlunoDAO" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Lista de alunos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Telefone</td>
        <td>Matricula</td>
        <td>Estado</td>
        <td>Endereco</td>
        <td>Idade</td>
        <td>Ação</td>
    </tr>
    <% 
        for(Aluno aluno : new AlunoDAO().list()){
    %>  
    <tr>
        <td><%=aluno.getId() %></td>
        <td><%=aluno.getNome()%></td>
        <td><%=aluno.getEmail() %></td>
        <td><%=aluno.getTelefone() %></td>
        <td><%=aluno.getMatricula() %></td>
            <%if(aluno.getAtivo() == true) {%>
            <td>Ativo</td>
              <%} else { %>
            <td>Desativado</td>
            <%} %>
        <td><%=aluno.getEndereco() %></td>
        <td><%=aluno.getIdade() %></td>
        <td><a href="alunoCONTROLLER?operacao=deletar&id=<%=aluno.getId()%>">Deleter</a></td>
        <td><a href="atualizar.jsp?id=<%=aluno.getId()%>">Editar</a></td>
  </tr>
  <%} %>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**AlunoDAO**

```
package DAO;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import MODEL.Aluno;

public class AlunoDAO implements IDAO{

private String sql;
private PreparedStatement pst;
private ResultSet rs;
private Connection connection;

public AlunoDAO(){
    if(connection == null){
        connection = new ConnectionFactory().getconnection();
    }
}

@Override
public void save(Aluno aluno) {
        sql = "insert into aluna(nome,"
            + " email,"
            + " matricula,"
            + " endereco,"
            + "telefone"
            + "idade,"
            + "ativo) "
            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {

    pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    pst.setString(1, aluno.getNome());
    pst.setString(2, aluno.getEmail());
    pst.setLong(3, aluno.getMatricula());
    pst.setString(4, aluno.getEndereco());
    pst.setLong(5, aluno.getTelefone());
    pst.setInt(6, aluno.getIdade());
    pst.setBoolean(7, aluno.getAtivo());

    pst.execute();
    pst.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void update(Aluno aluno) {
    sql = "update aluna set "
            + "nome=?,"
            + " telefone=?,"
            + " endereco=?, "
            + "idade=?, "
            + "email=?,"
            + "matricula=?,"
            + " ativo=? where id=?";

    try {

        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, aluno.getNome());
        pst.setString(2, aluno.getEmail());
        pst.setLong(3, aluno.getMatricula());
        pst.setString(4, aluno.getEndereco());
        pst.setLong(5, aluno.getTelefone());
        pst.setInt(6, aluno.getIdade());
        pst.setBoolean(7, aluno.getAtivo());
        pst.setInt(8, aluno.getId());

        pst.execute();
        pst.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


}

@Override
public void delete(Aluno aluno) {

    sql = "delete from aluna where id=?";

    try{
        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setInt(1, aluno.getId());

        pst.execute();
        pst.close();

    } catch (SQLException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

@Override
public Aluno find(Integer id) {
    Aluno aluno = null;
        sql = "select * from aluna where id=?";

    try {
        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, id);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            aluno = new Aluno();

            aluno.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            aluno.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            aluno.setAtivo(rs.getBoolean("ativo"));
            aluno.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            aluno.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
            aluno.setIdade(rs.getInt("idade"));
            aluno.setMatricula(rs.getLong("matricula"));
            aluno.setTelefone(rs.getLong("telefone"));
        }

        return aluno;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public List<Aluno> list() {

    List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
    Aluno aluno;
```

sql = "select * from aluna";

```
    try {
        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            aluno = new Aluno();

            aluno.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            aluno.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            aluno.setAtivo(rs.getBoolean("ativo"));
            aluno.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            aluno.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
            aluno.setIdade(rs.getInt("idade"));
            aluno.setMatricula(rs.getLong("matricula"));
            aluno.setTelefone(rs.getLong("telefone"));

            alunos.add(aluno);
        }

        return alunos;

    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: No arquivo de log do servidor de aplicações aparece algo?

Comment: Nada. O que aparece é aquela mensagem que o tomcat foi iniciado...

Comment: Você consegue depurar o seu método doGet?

Comment: Ahn. Boa ideia! Na ide, não é?

Comment: Isso. Poe um breakpoint e inicia o server no modo debug.

Comment: Como está sua classe AlunoDAO?

Comment: Olha isso aqui: JSP-> <input type="hidden" name="operacao" value="inserir" > Controller-> switch(operacao){
    case "incluir" [...]  Em um está "inserir" no outro "incluir"

Comment: Eu executei em mode debug e eu vi aqui que ele não entra em nenhuma opção switch Oo

Comment: @PedroTeles Era isso mesmo! Obrigada!!

Comment: @PedroTeles Você tem a oportunidade de criar a resposta para essa pergunta de acordo com seu comentário.